# How can I make a level generator script run in Edit Mode?

Tags: unity

### Description

I've a script that takes in a PNG bitmap (e.g. 8x8) and, reading from that, populates the grid with cells where alpha > 0.

### Problem

The script runs in `Awake()`, so it can only be seen in Play Mode. I want it to *always* appear in the scene, even in Edit Mode.

### Potential Solutions

I know of the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute, as well as the `OnValidate()` callback. I don't know which is better to use, though, or what pitfalls to avoid.

Additionally, in the past, I created a level generator that created a mesh, which I saved as an .asset with a custom editor button. The .asset was then loaded from inside the script. However, if possible, I'd like a more elegant — and automatic — solution.

### Other

I'm using Unity 2018.4, and the grid is isometric. (I'm *not* using Unity's built-in Tilemap.)

Comment: It sounds like you have a workable solution already. What concrete problem with this solution can we help you solve? What about it is currently not elegant or automatic enough?

Comment: You have to play the game to generate the terrain (grid, in this case), then click the save button before you exit it, save it manually as a file, exit Play Mode, and then I had another button for re-centering the mesh. If possible, I'd like the grid to be populated automatically when the bitmap is loaded and persist, or better yet, to have Unity's Tilemap-like editor and forgo the bitmap altogether. However, I need each cell to be an individual game object with its own collider and children I'll later assign to it, so I can't use the built-in Tilemap Editor.

Comment: "You have to play the game" You already cited two potential fixes for that. What do you want to improve about those solutions?